# SpringBoot angular App not serving all the js files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

We have an Angular App served through a SpingBoot application. When the developer who originally developed the app compiles a WAR package and deploy it on a TOMCAT server everything works fine.

But when others clone the source code and try to build and run the same code it doesn't work, ends up giving following errors in browser console. Seems "some" of the static content is not served. Can confirm the given files are in place with the other js files which gets served.

```
localhost/:40 GET http://localhost:8080/js/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.js 
localhost/:41 GET http://localhost:8080/js/angular-storage/dist/angular-storage.js 
localhost/:42 GET http://localhost:8080/js/auth0-angular/build/auth0-angular.min.js 
localhost/:40 GET http://localhost:8080/js/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.js 
(index):41 GET http://localhost:8080/js/angular-storage/dist/angular-storage.js 
(index):42 GET http://localhost:8080/js/auth0-angular/build/auth0-angular.min.js
```

We don't explicitly configure any MVC config, but rely on the Boot's defaults. ie. we've put all the static content in `/src/resources/static/` directory which boot is said to be serving by default. So right now it looks like below,

[image]

P.S.: Build system is maven at the moment.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some more details on how the static files are set up to be served at the moment? A snippet of your MVC config would help.

[Some reference on how to serve static files with SpringBoot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

Comment: Added more info on static content

Comment: You said that when deployed in tomcat everything works, how is the app deployed when not working? embedded tomcat?

Comment: yes embedded tomcat, even on embedded tomcat it only works when built and run on the original developer's machine.

Comment: Ok, thats weird :P if you request the resources directly (not from angular code) `curl http://localhost:8080/js/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.js` can you verify that spring fails to resolve the static resources on one of the broken dev envs?

Comment: Yea super weird :D `{"timestamp":1493804982408,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/js/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.js"}` this is the curl output

Comment: What's the full path for that file in the source code?

Comment: `<script src="js/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.js"></script>` it's put this way. Thing is `<script src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>` this works. It's only some of the JSs that doesn't get served.

Comment: I was referring to the path in the classpath. e.g. `/static/js/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.js` and verify that this actually exists, and is the same on your and your colleagues env. I know this is silly but im just trying to exclude this...

Comment: well it does exist there.

Comment: Try adding `logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG` to your `application.properties` to make the log tell you what is happening with the request when you request the resource

Comment: Did you follow this [instruction](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)? I had similar issue when forgot to extend SpringBootServletInitializer in the Boot-application entry class.

Comment: Actually we solved the issue. It was merely a mistaken .gitignore configuration causing the up-streams to have incomplete file listing except the original developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. It was nothing but few files inside angular dependencies bundled within not getting pushed to the upstream repos due to mishandled .gitignore file. One poor mistake.